# Youtube, downloading videos and local temporary files

Tags: copyright, youtube

Other posts have discussed whether downloading videos from Youtube is legal or not, but I want to point out something else.

When you stream a video from Youtube or another streaming service, the video is actually downloaded to your computer because else you can't really see it, and as such I can just go to the temp folder and copy paste it somewhere so as to avoid it being deleted.

Can that be rendered illegal? Or is it already?

Comment: What makes you think the video is downloaded? It's called streaming, your browser may "read ahead" to cache, but it doesn't download an MP4 and play it from disk... Just like my TV/Roku/Fire doesn't download the movies I stream because it doesn't have a disk at all...

Comment: The fact that you can find it.